# Consumer stops if stats is enabled - node-rdkafka

Tags: node.js, apache-kafka, librdkafka

I am using `node-rdkafka` to consume messages from kafka.
Consumer process exits if `statistics.interval.ms` is set.

Here is the code:

```
const { KafkaConsumer } = require('node-rdkafka')
const consumer = new KafkaConsumer(
    {
        'group.id': 'kafka',
        'metadata.broker.list': 'localhost:9092',
        'statistics.interval.ms': 5000,
    },
    {},
)
consumer
    .on('ready', () => {
        consumer.subscribe(['test1'])
        setInterval(() => {
            consumer.consume(1)
        }, 1000)
    })
    .on('data', (data) => {
        console.log('Message found!  Contents below.')
        console.log(data.value.toString())
    })
    .on('error', (e) => console.log(e))
```

This code just consumes one message and then exits. I checked `process.on` events as well but no error is thrown. If I remove `'statistics.interval.ms': 5000` then everything works fine

Comment: Try running it with logging set to debug and see if there's an exception there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is `windows` related problem. `Linux` works completely fine.

Answer (score 0):

```
consumer
    .on('ready', () => {
        consumer.subscribe(['test1'])
            consumer.consume()
    })
    .on('data', (data) => {
        console.log('Message found!  Contents below.')
        console.log(data.value.toString())
    })
    .on('error', (e) => console.log(e))
```

Try this and let me know if it work for you.